# How do i create a textfield that is editable directly on the page?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a page where the user can go in and edit a text on a button directly on the site. In this example the user should be able to edit the company's core values as shown at the bottom of my attached photo. Would really appreciate your help.

[image: Image of demo]

Comment: What have you already tried, and what problems are you currently having?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because i have no idea how to do it. Is it even possible to do with just html/css? I am kind of a newbie

Comment: if you just want to edit the text of a button you can use a lot of CSS to style the textfield to look like a button. ofcause the problem with that is that your click event will be to edit the button and wont work like a button anymore unless you use another button to "exit edit mode" and by clicking that you use javascript to alter the event listeners (thus binding a click function to the textarea to work like a button)

Comment: There are several methods you could choose. You could make them actual textfields and style them using CSS. You could also use javascript to listen for a click event and show a hidden text field that can then be edited and have it update the text within the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Lets say i skip to use those core values as buttons and just have them as textfields instead, what's the easiest way to do it then?

Comment: @RikardAbrahamsson you'd then just style the textarea to look like your button. as for saving you'd need javascript to make an AJAX call to the database to save the value as AJAX is the only way (i know of) to make server side calls on the client side

Comment: Did you look at `contentEditable`?

Answer (score 0):

it's a quite complicated process.

You can put the text of the buttons into input fields with JavaScript/JQuery and when the user save the changes save them into a database (I would prefer MySQL).

The text of the buttons should be loaded from the database.

Comment: Lets say i skip to use those core values as buttons and just have them as textfields instead, what's the easiest way to do it then?